# Difference between Doc data value constructor Char and Text

Tags: haskell

I am reading Real World Haskell, chapter 5 (writing JSON renderer).

```
data JValue = JString String
            | JNumber Double
            | JBool   Bool
            | JNull   
            ... 

data Doc = Empty
         | Char Char
         | Text String  
         | Concat Doc Doc
         ....
```

I cannot understand the difference 
between Char and Text (Doc Value Constructor).

```
renderJValue :: JValue -> Doc
renderJValue (JNumber n)        = Text $ show n
renderJValue (JBool   b)        = Text $ show b
renderJValue JNull              = Text "null"
renderJValue (JString (a:b:[])) = render a `Concat` render b 
    where render c = if isEscapeChar(c) 
                         then Text (c : [])
                         else Char c 


renderJValue $ JNumber 3                 
    = Text "3"
renderJValue $ JNull                     
    = Text "null"
renderJValue $ JString ("null")          
    = Char 'n' `Concat` Char 'u' `Concat` Char 'l' `Concat` Char 'l'
renderJValue $ JString ('a' : '\n' : []) 
    = Char 'a' `Concat` Text "\n"
```

What is an advantage of distinguish Char and Text ?

Comment: I suspect you're missing some context.

Answer (score 3):

`Text` takes a `String` argument. `Char` takes a single `Char` value. As defined:

```
data Doc = Empty
         | Char Char
         | Text String
         | Line
         | Concat Doc Doc
         | Union Doc Doc
           deriving (Show,Eq)
```

Your example has a type error, it seems, since you're passing a '\n' to Text on the final line.

Comment: thanks. it's my mistake. i modified it. Text String can be represented Char. in the book, if the string contains escape character , for example JValue ('\x1ff' : '\x1ff' : []) , then generate Text "\x1ff" `Concat` Text "\x1ff" . I think it could be Char '\x1ff' `Concat` Char '\x1ff' . i think Text value constructor is useless. I am confused with it.

Comment: @Don Stewart: So why is there a separate `Char` constructor, what is its advantage compared to just using `Text . (:[])`?

Comment: Char and Text are different types. You might want to print one with single quotes, and one with double, for example.